# Bibliography sorting options with Classic Thesis

Tags: bibliographies, classicthesis

I would like to have the entries in my bibliography numbered using the citation order but I cannot find a way to do it.

I tried to set the order with `\bibliographystyle` using both `none` and `unsrt` as parameter but that didn't work.

Any ideas?

=EDIT=
I thank Václav Pavlík but I solved as commented under the question.
I realized after that the comment in not really visible.

Comment: `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}`, maybe?

Comment: Nop, still as before.

Comment: Have you tried loading `natbib` and using `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If the stock recommendations don't help (and you seem to have tried some of those), you might want to prepare a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) for us, so we can investigate your issue in more detail. Please keep the MWE short and concise.

Comment: It's the default with `biblatex` (`numeric` style).

Comment: Preparing the minimal example I saw suddenly the desired order -- the citation order -- appear O.o.
So I manually deleted all the temp files -- .aux, .bbl, .blg, .lof, .log, etc -- and that together with `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}` did the job. Now the problem is solved but I just would like to know if this is normal or is something in my build setting that's off. Thanks to everybody.

Answer (score 3):

Since version 4.2 the Classic Thesis template uses `biblatex`  for bibliography generation.  The references will appear in their citation order by passing the option `sorting=none` to biblatex. The default for the template has been set in `classicthesis-config.tex` to `sorting=nyt` (name, year, title).

Answer (score 0):

Use BibTex and the package `natbib` and `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}`. Here is the minimal example:

Bibliography will be in both cases (below) the same:`ex.bib`

```
@Article{john_doe,
 author = {{Doe}, J.},
 title = "{\it John's Doe book}",
 journal = {Book or journal},
 year = {2014},
 volume = "{\bf 1}",
 pages = {5--10},
}

@Article{foo_bar,
 author = {{Bar}, F.},
 title = "{\it Bar, bar book}",
 journal = {Book or journal},
 year = {2014},
 volume = "{\bf 1}",
 pages = {5--10},
}
```

Depending on the format of the document, you will get different results.

If the document `ex.tex` looks like

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

Some text here \citep[cited by][]{john_doe}, and some other text by \cite{foo_bar}.

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{ex}{}

\end{document}
```

you get

[image: page1]
[image: page2]

If the document `ex.tex` looks like

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

Some text here \citep[cited by][]{foo_bar}, and some other text by \cite{john_doe}.

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{ex}{}

\end{document}
```

you get

[image: page1]
[image: page2]

Comment: There really shouldn't be *any* hand-formatting instructions such as `\it` and `\bf` in a bib file -- quite apart from the fact that these two particular macros are deprecated under LaTeX. The formatting of the contents of fields such as `journal` and `volume` is set in the bibliography style file, and it's counterproductive to override those settings by providing instructions such as `\it` and `\bf`.

Comment: Note that classicthesis template has recently switched to biblatex (with biber or bibtex8 as the backends).

Comment: @PhilipPirrip Do you want to add an alternative solution focussing `biblatex`?

Answer (score 0):

For me, putting `sorting=none` in `classic-thesis.tex` together with removing the temporary files manually (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.blg`, `.lof`, `.log`) solved the problem.